# Xcode live debugging - sending notifications to running app

Tags: xcode

I have seen stuff like superDB, where you can sent Notifications to the app while it is running. https://github.com/Shopify/superdb

I know that in llvm, you can add subviews etc. when hitting a breakpoint.

Is it possible to sent notification in any other way than using superDB?

Thanks
Regards

Comment: Well, YES, can you give more context on what it is you are trying to do? there are many ways to achieve this. superDB is doing a few things; it has the F-Script virtual machine running on the iOS device and a network layer to the MAC app. There are some similar things out there (Pony Debugger for example) but it's hard to be specific when your question is vague. hope that helps...

Comment: Hi Joe, I am looking for a way to see UI changes, when tweaking the UI.

Comment: Check out http://www.sparkinspector.com/ it might do what you're looking for. Lets you tweak UI settings on the fly and see the results in the running app instantly. It now has an Xcode plugin that lets you use it without installing a static library into your app. It has saved me hours of work! There is also http://revealapp.com/ which is similar, though I found it wasn't as good when I tried it (yet it's more expensive).

Answer (score 0):

In terms of being able to edit the UI in real time [SuperDB](http://shopify.github.io/superdb/) is very, very powerful. What I've done in my app is make it so when I click on a UI object, this becomes accessible via the .self command - it's made tweaking the UI very easy and it's lots of fun to interface with your app this way. Downside is that there is a bit of a learning curve.

Some other options to consider:

- [DCIntrospect UIKit](https://github.com/domesticcatsoftware/DCIntrospect/wiki) is an interface examiner - I've not used it but looks like it might do some of what you are looking for

> Introspect is small set of tools for iOS that aid in debugging user interfaces built with UIKit. It's especially useful for UI layouts that are dynamically created or can change during runtime, or for tuning performance by finding non-opaque views or views that are re-drawing unnecessarily. It's designed for use in the iPhone simulator, but can also be used on a device.

- [PonyDebugger](https://github.com/square/PonyDebugger#readme) Uses Chrome to remote into you app. Good for network traffic debugging, Core Data browsing, view hierarchy displaying

> PonyDebugger is a remote debugging toolset. It is a client library and gateway server combination that uses Chrome Developer Tools on your browser to debug your application's network traffic and managed object contexts.

- [Guesture Lab](https://github.com/markd2/GestureLab) ... if you are looking for debuging input too.

> Playground for gesture recognizers.